# What packages do I need to add to a .NET Core Project to be able to scaffold?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build a skeleton framework using using EF Core and MVC .NET Core. Just added a new Console Project (not sure if that is the best option) 'Site.Business' that will hold the business logic and Controllers. 'New Scaffold Item' is missing.

Is there some NuGet package i need to add to this layer to be able to right click and scaffold a new controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using .Net Core 2.0 version,Better to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package which will install all the required dependencies for creating Asp.Net Core application. You have created console application which is fine. Just install Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package.

Additionally follow the tutorial from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio-code)

Follow the appropriate section whether you are using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code